# Probability of rolling a yahtzee when you have rolled three of a kind

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, independence

*First and foremost I want to apologize that I'm asking a question that has probably been asked before but I'm not able to find it.*

> What is the probability of rolling a Yahtzee when you have already rolled three $4$'s  on your first roll?

The answer here is gotten by first finding out about the three different scenarios which you could roll the same value for the last two dice. That would be scenarios;

$$(1)\ Rolling\ two\ 4's\ on\ your\ first\ try = \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6}$$

$$(2)\ Rolling\ two\ 4's\ on\ last\ try\ = \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6}$$

$$(3)\ Rolling\ one\ 4\ on\ your\ first\ and \ one \ on \ your \ last= \frac{5}{6} * \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}*\frac{5}{6}$$

My last scenario is wrong and I don't understand why. I thought the intuitive way to do this would be to not roll a $4$ then roll one, and then again you add that to the scenario of rolling a $4$ and not rolling a $4$.

If anyone could solve this using combinatorics that would also be a great way to learn for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first roll, you will roll
\begin{align*}
  \text{two 4's with probability }&\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36} \\
  \text{no 4's with probability }&\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6} = \frac{25}{36} \\
  \text{exactly one 4 with probability }&1 - \frac{1}{36} - \frac{25}{36} = \frac{10}{36}.
\end{align*}
In the second case, your chances of rolling two 4's with your last roll is again $\frac{1}{36}$. In the third case, you are rolling one die; your chances of getting a 4 are $\frac{1}{6}$. So the total probability of rolling a Yahtzee is
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{36} + \frac{25}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{36} + \frac{10}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{6} = \frac{121}{1296}\approx 0.0933642,.
\end{equation*}